# Invalidate a chunk's cache when uncached chunk changes

Tags: r, knitr

I have a question regarding the knitr chunk option "dependson". As far as I understood the manual this option should be used to specify which other cached chunks a cached chunk depends on. But is there a way to invalidate a chunk's cache when an *uncached* chunk changes?

Here's a minimal example:

File *knitrtest.Rnw*:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

<<>>=
library(knitr)

read_chunk("chunks.R")
@

<<not_cached>>=
@

<<cached, cache=TRUE, dependson="not_cached">>=
@

\end{document}
```

File *chunks.R*:

```
## @knitr not_cached
var <- 42

## @knitr cached
var
```

When I change *var* the output from chunk "cached" is still 42 as the dependson option doesn't apply.
In my example I could solve the problem by caching the first chunk, too. However, I cannot do that because in the first chunk I use `library()` and read in external files, so this chunk should not be cached.

Is there a way to invalidate cache when a not cached chunk changes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can make `var` a part of the chunk options, e.g.

```
<<cached, cache=TRUE, cache.whatever=var>>=
@
```

`cache.whatever` is not an official chunk option name, but you can use arbitrary options in `knitr`, and they will affect the cache invalidation. In this case, when `var` is updated, the cache will be updated.

If you want `var` to affect all cached chunks, you can set it as a global option, but remember to set it as an unevaluated expression:

```
opts_chunk$set(cache.whatever = quote(var))
```

You can use arbitrary R expressions inside `quote()`, so if you have more variables, you can put them in a list, e.g.

```
opts_chunk$set(cache.whatever = quote(list(var1, var2)))
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, Yihui! What you suggested works when applied to each chunk separately but it seems like I cannot set `cache.whatever=var` as a global chunk option. Using `opts_chunk$set(cache.whatever=var)` has no effect. Is there a solution for this issue as well?

Comment: That works, thank you again! Maybe you should mention this in http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/cache/ ? By the way, it seems to me like setting `opts_chunk$set(cache.whatever = quote(foo))` throws an error unless `foo` is defined beforehand. One last question: neither `cache.whatever=c(quote(foo), quote(bar))` nor `cache.whatever=list(quote(foo), quote(bar))` seems to work. Is there any other way to use more than one variable per option?

Comment: @user2706569 Please feel free to [help me](http://yihui.name/en/2013/06/fix-typo-in-documentation/) update the documentation. For your last question, see the edited answer above.

Comment: I'm not sure if I can describe the problem and its solution accurately enough, but I will try to contribute to the documentation whenever I am able to do so. Thank you for amending your answer!