# Intelligently cache in R Markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

Knitr provides the option to cache the output of chunks using the `cache=TRUE` option. This is very useful if a script contains large amount of processing which doesn't need to be updated that often.

However, the cache will only be updated if the code in the chunk is changed, or the cache file is deleted. This is not always ideal, as there may be a slow process which relies on options specified outside of the chunk.

Is it possible to have the cache checks to see the input parameters used within the chunk, and updates if these have been changed?

### Example

Here is a minimal example:

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

```{r}
x <- "Title 1"
```

```{r cars, cache=TRUE}
plot(cars, main = x)
```
````

When you run this the first time, it will output the figure below. If we change the value of `x` to something else, such as `Title 2`, it will not update the title of the plot on the second run.

[image]

In my ideal solution, `knitr` would detect that the value of `x` changes, and therefore refresh the cache.

From what I can see, nothing is mentioned along these lines in the documentation: https://yihui.name/knitr/options/#cache

Comment: Does this answer make sense? https://stackoverflow.com/a/18394790/3358272

Comment: That is, set your second code block header to `{r cars, cache=TRUE, cache.quux=x}`.

Comment: I'll mark it as a dupe, recommend you go up-vote the other question and answer.

Comment: `{r cars, cache=TRUE, cache.whatever=list(x,y,z)}` works for me, is that enough, or is there something more complex?

Comment: Comment deleted after fixing the problem!  Classic late night coding errors... thanks for the help